# Identify primary topic area from the list provided to which the abstract is best suited

Tags: meaning

> Identify primary topic area from the list provided to which the abstract is best suited

The sentence as shown above. I am not sure what's sentence meaning and as it is a clause structure, can we divide it into two seperate sentences. I think in that way I will understand it eaily.

Answer (score 1):

> Identify the primary topic area from the list provided to which the abstract is best suited.

You can break the sentence down like this:

1. A list of topics is provided.
2. One topic should be most relevant to the abstract.
3. Identify that "best" topic.

"to which the abstract is best suited" refers to "primary topic area".

"from the list provided" refers to the range of possible choices for identification.